Forward-over-reverse mode Hessian-vector product in Jax: how smart is jax.jvp at re-using computations?
How smart is Jax at re-using intermediate computations when computing Hessian-vector products via forward-over-reverse mode automatic differentiation via jax.jvp over jax.grad?
For example, something like this:
def objective(x, other):
    ...expensive function, returns a scalar...

gradient = jax.grad(objective, argnums=0)

@jax.jit
def hessian_vector_product(p, x, other): # computes H(x) @ p
    g, Hp = jax.jvp(lambda z: gradient(z, other), (x,), (p,))
    return Hp

Now we call
hessian_vector_product(p1, x, other)
hessian_vector_product(p2, x, other)
hessian_vector_product(p3, x, other)
...

with different p1, p2, p3, ..., but the same x, other.
A common scenario where this occurs is inexact Newton-CG optimization. In this case, many Hessian vector products are taken at the same point x, but for different directions p which are chosen by the conjugate gradient algorithm.
From a mathematical point of view, we know that the forward tangent variables (found when computing the objective), and adjoint tangent variables (found when computing the gradient), remain the same and can be re-used as long as x and other do not change. Does Jax figure that out, or are the forward and adjoint variables re-computed every time, thereby roughly doubling the cost?
If the code above unnecessarily re-computes intermediate variables, is there another, better way in Jax to do Hessian vector products? Preferably, using forward-over-reverse mode AD, because that is generally the recommended approach in books on AD (e.g., see chapter 3 in "The Art of Differentiating Computer Programs" by Uwe Naumann).
